# Programmatically render a custom form in a view template while passing view argument to form

Tags: views, theming, forms

I have built a custom form (in its own module using FORM API) and have exposed this form also as a block using Plugin API.

I can add this form fine to page and get it to render using Block Layout but it doesnt appear in the correct place.

I am trying to get it to appear in the main page content of a `Page View` which has a Header and Footer. The form seems to appear after the footer content, even after shifting the block around in the block layout.

So now I have been trying to use the various view template hooks by loading the form via the snippet:

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('auctioncataloguerequestform');
$block_content = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('block')
    ->view($block);
$variables['form_auction_cat_request'] = $block_content;
```

`auctioncataloguerequestform` is the machine name of the "form block" added to Block Layouts (Its in the content section, but disabled)

But in XDebug I cannot find the `form_auction_cat_request` variable and `{{ form_auction_cat_request }}` renders nothing.

Hooks I tried using where: `template_preprocess_views_view`, `template_preprocess_views_view_field` and `template_preprocess_views_view_unformatted`

At the moment I am simply trying to get the form to render but once this is done I then need to pass a `string` variable which is a field of the view in question to be passed to the form.

Am I on the right track or completely missing the mark?

View screenshot

[image: Auctions view]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print form before the views:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
  $form = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\mymodule\Form\DefaultForm');
  $variables['attachment_before'][] = $form;
}
```

===

Another way is to add your custom form and the views in own controller (and route),

In views add filters and expose them, set exposed in block = yes (this will detach the form from the views),

in exposed filters settings set the names as they are in your form - for each one,

make your form to redirect on submit to the route passing the values as query params (?param_name=value&param_name2=value2), for multiple select or checkboxes params are in format: param_name[6]=6&param_name[17]=17

the rest will be done by views - it will get params automatically

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\views\Views;

/**
 * Class DefaultController.
 */
class DefaultController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Content.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Return Content string.
   */
  public function content() {

    $elements = [];

    $elements['form_search'] = \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm('\Drupal\mymodule\Form\DefaultForm');
    $elements['form_search']['#weight'] = 0;

    $views_name = 'machine_views_name';
    $display_id = 'page_1';
    $view = Views::getView($views_name);
    $view->setDisplay($display_id);

    $elements['view'] = $view->render($display_id);
    $elements['view']['#weight'] = 1;

    return $elements;
  }

}
```

example module with controller, form and exported views "Content list": https://github.com/svetlio/mymodule

Comment: The first suggestion worked for me for displaying the form correctly, still can't inject a string variable though. Will investigate further today on that. Thanks for the help

Comment: There are 2 keys points for this: 1. Add a filter field in the views to search in ("Title" for ex.), expose him, change the "Filter identifier" in a filter conf to "string" for ex.; 2. On submit pass the value to $_GET['string'], so url should look like "/your_views_path?string=something+to+search". You can test it just by typing this kind of url to see results in the views, then research how to redirect your form "on submit" to this url.